# Github Action - How can I trigger a workflow when argocd deployment is finished?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, github-actions, pipeline, argocd

I'm working in a company that uses Github Actions and Argocd.(using argocd helm chart).
Needless to say that the Github repo is private and argocd is in an internal network that used by the company only.

The flow of what we want to do is that when we deploy the app and the deployment succeeded - Trigger another workflow that will run tests on the deployed environment.
Basically, the deployment will be the trigger for another workflow.

I have been trying to configure webhook from argocd to github but with no success.
What is the best approach to this situation, will be happy to provide more context if needed.

Edit:
The test workflow i'm trying to use workflow_dispatch.

```
name: workflow_02
on:
  push:
    branches: [ argo-github-trigger ]
  workflow_dispatch:


jobs:
  log-the-inputs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "Worked"
```

I'm expecting to see a "Run workflow" button on github but it doesn't appear. On another repo, that I have Admin priviliges and can work on the main branch, I tried the same workflow and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to use a [post sync hook](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/resource_hooks/).

Why is it necessary to run the tests in a GitHub actions workflow? Since the application is already deployed to the cluster, wouldn't it make more sense to run the tests directly on the cluster, instead of going through the trouble of communicating with Github?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. maybe I was not clear about the flow of what I want to do. I want to deploy to a staging environment, run tests and trigger a deployment to production environment only if the test passed. I'm open to hear other ways of doing it, running the tests on the cluster might do the trick but i stil need argo to signal github that the sync has completed successfully.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was something of this sort. If this is the case, what's stopping you from using the dispatch event to trigger a workflow using the GitHub api?
Reference - https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow

Comment: I have been trying to do it, but when I add workflow_dispatch event to trigger a workflow the option to trigger it doesn't appear on github. I'm working on a private repo, not on the default branch, is that might be the issue ?

Comment: Not likely, we were using workflow_dispatch in a private repo in my previous workplace and it worked very similar to what you are trying to achieve. Maybe it's something about how you added it to the workflow.yaml? If you edit your question and add it there I can take a look.

Comment: I edited the question with the workflow, did a basic test to try and make it work.

Comment: This is basically what i need to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917361/how-to-run-application-e2e-test-after-argocd-deployment?rq=1 I'm missing the part of making workflow_dispatch works on a non default branch.

Comment: Well, first may I suggest you ask for admin privileges on the repo you are working on? If the setup works for another repository, it's very likely missing permissions are the issue here.